# HTML5 Presentation in Safari: Enter Full Screen

Tags: html, rstudio, r-markdown, presentation

does anyone know how to enter the fullscreen mode of a ioslides presentation in Safari? It's supposed to work by pressing 'F'. But that doesn't work for me. It does work in Chrome though :/...

Regards,
Martin

Comment: Version 8.0.6 (10600.6.3)

Comment: which operating system ?

Comment: Try using : `Control-Command-F` to enter normal press `escape`

Comment: Well I come into a fullscreen mode using that shortcut, but still not the "real fullscreen" where only the slides are visible.